# Why does my Image stretch when I crop it?

Tags: php, gd

I am using the following code snippet in order to crop a image?

```
   function crop($width,$height) {
       $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
       imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight(), $width, $height );
       $this->image = $new_image;
   }
```

Here, `$this->image` is the original image `$this->getWidth()` and `$this->getHeight()` holds the original dimensions of the picture, where as `$width` and `$height`, is the crop area.

But for some reason, the crop image is resized(we can almost say it is resized).

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the problem is giving the source dimensions. Giving the dimensions of entire image will re size instead of cropping.

This should solve the problem

```
   function crop($width,$height) {
       $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
       imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height );
       $this->image = $new_image;
   }
```

Comment: Also have a look at http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com.br/2009/04/crop-to-fit-image-using-aspphp.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have a solution for uploaded image crop and resize without starch
please Following this steps:

step 1: you make a new index.php file.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="image_upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

step 2 : then make a new file resize.php

```
<?php

        Class resize
        {
            // *** Class variables
            private $image;
            private $width;
            private $height;
            private $imageResized;

            function __construct($fileName)
            {

                // *** Open up the file
               $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);

                // *** Get width and height
                $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
                $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------
            public static function openImage($file)
            {


                // *** Get extension
                $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

                switch($extension)
                {
                    case '.jpg':
                    case '.jpeg':
                        $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                        break;
                    case '.gif':
                        $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
                        break;
                    case '.png':
                        $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
                        break;
                    default:
                        $img = false;
                        break;
                }

                return $img;
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
            {
                // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
                $optionArray =  $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

                $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


                // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
                $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
                imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


                // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
                if ($option == 'crop') {
                    $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
                }
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option)
            {
               switch ($option)
                {
                    case 'exact':
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                        break;
                    case 'portrait':
                        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                        break;
                    case 'landscape':
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                        break;
                    case 'auto':
                        $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
                        $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                        break;
                    case 'crop':
                        $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
                        $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                        break;
                }
                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public static function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)
            {
                $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
                $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
                return $newWidth;
            }

            public static function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)
            {
                $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
                $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
                return $newHeight;
            }

            public static function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)
            {
                if ($this->height < $this->width)
                // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
                {
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                }
                elseif ($this->height > $this->width)
                // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
                {
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                }
                else
                // *** Image to be resizerd is a square
                {
                    if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                    } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
                        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    } else {
                        // *** Sqaure being resized to a square
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    }
                }

                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
            {

                $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
                $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;

                if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
                    $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
                } else {
                    $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
                }

                $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
                $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
            {
                // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
                $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
                $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

                $crop = $this->imageResized;
                //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

                // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
                $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
                imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100")
            {
                // *** Get extension
                $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
                $extension = strtolower($extension);

                switch($extension)
                {
                    case '.jpg':
                    case '.jpeg':
                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                            imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                        }
                        break;

                    case '.gif':
                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                            imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                        }
                        break;

                    case '.png':
                        // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                        $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                        // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
                        $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                             imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                        }
                        break;

                    // ... etc

                    default:
                        // *** No extension - No save.
                        break;
                }

                imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
            }


            ## --------------------------------------------------------

        }
?>
```

step 3 : you also make a new two folder 1) image and 2) image_thumb

step 4 : then after make a new file image_upload.php

```
<?php
include('resize.php');
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){

    //set a folder move to orignal images
    $destinationPath = "image/";

    //set a folder move to crop and resizeable images
    $destinationThumbPath = "image_thumb/";

    //uploaded files extension 
    $extension = strtolower(strrchr($_FILES['image']['name'], '.'));

    //set a new custom name of uploaded file
    $file_name = "image_".rand('1111','9999').$extension;

    //move orignal image in Destination Path  
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],"image/".$file_name);

    //set a new thumbnail width 
    $newWidth = 96;
    //set a new thumbnail height
    $newHeight = 96;
    //profile image resize
    $resizeObj = new resize($destinationPath . $file_name);
    // *** 2) Resize image (options: exact, portrait, landscape, auto, crop)
    $resizeObj->resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, 'crop');

    //crop and resize image save in destination path
    $resizeObj->saveImage($destinationThumbPath . $file_name, 100);

}  
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is what imagecopyresampled does: it rescales the image and does not crop it. Try imagecopy instead.

Comment: No it's not.  `imagecopy` and `imagecopyresampled` work the same way.  The difference between them, is that `imagecopy` just "scales" the pixels up or down depending on the move.  `imagecopyresampled` interpolates pixel values when resizing (so it makes a "smoother" and better looking image).  But both do crop and/or resize the image...